# how to play a video with Android or AndEngine

Tags: android, video

I don't know if it's possible to show a video like the videos in Angry Birds (Something in Flash or another format) in middle of a game with Android or AndEngine or are they animations what they are made with Sprites and a more programming process?? How do they show those videos?